# How to create a wirless audio headphone

Tags: audio, wireless

I am working on a small project and this is my requirement:
I already have a headphone which I can plug into an audio jack. I need to make this headphone wireless. Right now all I can think of is attach an audio sender dongle to the two line audio jack and a receiver at the other end.Is this the right way to go? Or are there some other alternatives?
The key area that I would like to focus on is building the radio transmission along with its reciever. Needless to say the bluetooth protocol is something i would definitely have to focus on.

Comment: Wireless headphones have been available for years. What is it about your application that requires a custom design?

Comment: I want to build it myself and not use prebuilt headphones(both for the expirience and the fun of it)

Comment: This question needs revision.  The scope is enormous and topics could range from signal analysis, to radio transmission, to bluetooth protocols.  I suggest changing the question to reflect what learning experiences are you hoping to gain from this project.

Comment: @DeveloperAndroid - Are you looking to build your own circuit? (i.e. solder various electronic compoents together) or buy a dongle of some sort?

Comment: @Oli Glassler -Yes, I am looking to build my own circuit.

Comment: Typical wireless headphone designs use an FM radio transmitter on the sending side and an FM radio receiver on the headphones capable of tuning to the right frequency the transmitter is sending.

Comment: Yes Jon has it right. These products may vary in quality of SNR and distortion, but are very cheap and some have LCD's with tTx freq. and arrow keys,. for $17, without for $12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking into exactly the same project and I rules out Bluetooth and Wifi. Bluetooth has some serious interference issues, especially in places where wifi networks already exists. It will not be very reliable and sound quality will suffer.

The best solution I have found so far is Kleer Wireless technology which is distributed by SMSC. It's the technology used by Sennheiser for their high end wireless headsets. Like you, I would like to use my own headsets, I have nice Bose QC15 and they would work much better than any pre-built headsets.

Here is a link to their chip: http://www.smsc.com/index.php?tid=346

I did contact them and they have sent me a bunch of stuff but my knowledge in electronic is limited and I have to say I'm a bit stuck..

**[Update]
Since then I have actually made progress. I bought a used pair of Sennheiser RS160 and took the headset appart. Then I unsoldered the battery holder (which are part of the headset, and un-soldered the speakers and put and female 3.5mm Jack instead. I bought a standard battery holder for 2 AAA and here you go. Slapped all this in a box and you got your self a device on which you can plug your nice headset. Works like a charm.**

hope this helps you,
cheers
Antony

Comment: Any documentation on why Bluetooth and Wfifi won't work?

Comment: Thats pretty cool!!

Comment: wifi and bluetooth won't work mostly for two reasons: Bandwidth requirements and latency.. The 2.4GHZ band is shared by all devices you have in your house and around.. Kleer uses 3Mhz versus bluetooth at 20x1Mhz.. Wifi is more. Less chance of drops. Kleer's latency is <45ms, bluetooth ~100ms (too high) and wifi is way more.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start with something simple like IR audio transmission. The most easy thing to do is shown here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAYl_uNmpLo

More advanced circuits look like that: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/815/infraredsystem.gif/